# Construct file paths with different choices of extensions

Tags: python, regex

I would like to ask whether we have ways to construct file paths so that they can be true either for the first extension or the second extension when the code is executed.

For example, I have a variable like this `photo = f"{IMAGES_DIR}/{id}/{photo_folder}/{photo_folder}-original.png"`. Now, I wanna extend its ability to receive 'jpg', like `photo = f"{IMAGES_DIR}/{id}/{photo_folder}/{photo_folder}-original.jpg|png"`.

I think of using regular expressions, but to be honest, I don't know how to handle them in this case.

I hope to receive some help from you guys. Thanks!

Context provided: This is an API that I wrote. The body of the post method in Postman is {id: 'some id', photo_folder: 'some folder name}. In the past, the database just had png images, but now there are jpg images added. That's why I wanna extend that 'photo' variable so that it can deal with jpg images.

Comment: It looks like you are using fstrings, so the rest of the file path is created based on variables. Why not just include a file extension variable? If you want you could check the file extension variable and raise an error if it isn't the string "jpg" or "png" before you create the photo path.

Comment: The thing is jpg and png both exist in my database. Therefore, both are valid. That's why I wanna make the `photo` variable as a placeholder to receive either of them.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused on just what you're asking. Please provide additional context for exactly what you are trying to do, preferably by editing your question. Are you trying validate a string matches some pattern or construct a path-like string based on variables?

Comment: I added the context. Hope it is more obvious now.

Comment: what @R.Arctor told you is correct make a variable that holds the extension check if it's png or jpg if not raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed validating a path-like string based on the file extension this'll do it:

```py
import re

photo = 'dir1/id/dir2/filename.jpg'

# the object returned by re.search has implicit booleaness
if re.search(r'(.jpg|.png)$', photo):
    print('photo ends with .jpg or .png')

# pretty straight forward without regex
if photo.endswith('.jpg') or photo.endswith('.png'):
    print('photo ends with .jpg or .png')
```

Some useful docs:

- [str.enswith docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)
- [re.search docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.search)

If you're also validating a constructed path you could get fancy with your regex

```py
import re
# .*? matches anything in a non-greedy fashion
regex = r'^.*?/.*?/.*?/.*?-original.(png|jpg)$'
# fstrings with regex
some_var = 'some string'
fregex = rf'^{some_var}/file.(png|jpg)$'
# fregex = r'^some string/file.(png|jpg)$'
```

then use either with `re.search`. I find https://regex101.com/ really helpful when constructing regex strings. You should also note that `jpeg` is a valid file extension for jpg files.

If you are instead constructing path-like strings based on variables check out `os.path.join` and disregard everything above. [Docs for os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Or you could use variables with a python fstring, [docs on f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).